# Html confirmation popup on submit button

Tags: javascript, asp.net, html, web

In my application i have submit button which called store procedure in my db also on same page a have textbox which required data in it. I used required field validator for that textbox. And Ajax conformition thing for my submit button and confirm validation fire if text box is empty. I need check if that textbox is filed with data firs and only after that conformation should fire on button. I don't want popup fire before required field validation.

Comment: I am far from my computer will show it later

Comment: @AndreyIvanov Usually if that's the case you could make something up that's similar.

Comment: @AndreyIvanov: Well in that case you wouldn't need this answer right now right? You should present your question in such a way that you don't get question on the question. If someone asks to show what you have tried you must show it using your work we can suggest you some relevant to your work. Please don't ask any question if you can't provide further information on your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like

```
var button = document.getElementById('button'); // or whatever ID your button has
var textbox = document.getElementById('textbox'); //or whatever ID your input has
button.onclick = function() {
    if (textbox.value === "") {
        return false;
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this code

```
jQuery('#<%= button.ClientID %>').click(function(){
    if(jQuery('#<%= textbox.ClientID%>').val()=='')
    {
         return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return(confirm('Are you sure?'));
    }
});
```